# Mistake in Spyder setting

Tags: python, spyder

I have a little problem in using Spyder to run a python program: 
This is my program:

```
 from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
    from pyoppinet.helper.correlation_manager import *
    import pyoppinet.network as nt
    import numpy as np
    from pyoppinet.node import node
    from pyoppinet.GUI import network_view as nw
    from pyoppinet.pipe.flowline import Flowline


    network = nt.PipeLineNetwork(1000.2000)

    source1 = node.Source(10,200)
    source1.name = 'source1'

    source2 = node.Source(150,500)
    source2.name = 'source2'

    source3 = node.Source(200,400)
    source3.name = 'source3'

    junction1 =node.Junction(150,600)
    junction1.name = 'junction'

    sink =node.Sink(300,800)
    sink.name = 'sink'

    for n in [source1,source2,source3,junction1,sink]:
        network.add_node(n)


    fl1=Flowline(source1,junction1)
    fl2=Flowline(junction1,sink)
    fl3=Flowline(source2,sink)
    fl4=Flowline(source2,junction1)
    fl5=Flowline(source3,sink)
    fl6=Flowline(source3,junction1)



    for n in [fl1,fl2,fl3,fl4,fl5,fl6]:
        network.add_flowline(n)

    print [n.name for n in network.get_nodes()]
    print 'topological sort', [n.name for n in network.topological_sort()]


a=QApplication([])
view=nw.PipeLineNetworkView(network)
view.show()
a.exec_()
```

These two rows:

```
from pyoppinet.helper.correlation_manager import *
import numpy as np
```

are error.

And the error is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\program oppinet\latihan\latihan.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyoppinet.helper.correlation_manager import *

  File "D:\program oppinet\pyoppinet\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import GUI
  File "D:\program oppinet\pyoppinet\GUI\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    """
  File "D:\program oppinet\pyoppinet\GUI\viewmodelbase.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\program oppinet\pyoppinet\GUI\framework\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    # Copyright Â© 2011 Pierre Raybaut
  File "D:\program oppinet\pyoppinet\GUI\framework\GUI_helper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\program oppinet\pyoppinet\helper\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    # Copyright Â© 2011 Pierre Raybaut
  File "D:\program oppinet\pyoppinet\helper\UnitInfo.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "D:\program oppinet\pyoppinet\C_API\converter.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "D:\program oppinet\pyoppinet\C_API\converter.py", line 18, inswig_import_helper
 ImportError: No module named _converter
```

I believe that the error is caused by the setting in spyder, maybe in tools or something.
Could I change some setting in spyder to fix this problem?

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Are you able to run your program outside Spyder? I say it because I don't see how Spyder is involved in the error message you posted.

Comment: I just try to import numpy as np, but in spyder, it is marked with an error sign

Comment: I think the flagged error comes from this line `from pyoppinet.helper.correlation_manager import *` because star (`*`) imports don't let Spyder detect and suggest if an undefined name is trying to be used in your code or not. However, this is just a warning and doesn't have any effect during code's execution.